# change background color of an event of jquery event calendar by inserting value in mysql database

Tags: jquery, mysql, events, background, fullcalendar

I have a JQuery event calendar in which events are showing I want a click function that changes the background color of the event and also insert a value for permanent color change. I also want a code that runs that changed color event calendar.
This is my event calendar code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Uploaded').hide();

    $('#chang').click(function () {
        $('#Uploaded').show('slow');
    });

    $('#chang2').click(function () {
        $('#Uploaded').show('slow');
    });

    $('.fc-event-skin').live("click", function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#090');
        $(this).css('border-color', '#090');
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        editable: true,
        eventColor: '#cd3427',    
        events: "json-events.php",    
        buttonText: {
            today: 'idag'
        },
        monthNames: ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Mars', 'April', 'Maj', 'Juni', 'Juli',
                     'Augusti', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'],    
        dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
                   'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],

        eventDrop: function (event, delta) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "drag.php",
                data: "date=" + delta + "&id=" + event.id,
                success: function (msg) {
                    //alert( "Data Saved: " + "id="+ event.id +"&date="+ delta );
                }
            });

        },

        loading: function (bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: You are already doing an ajax call for eventDrop.  Can you do another one for click and UPDATE the background color in the db with that?

Comment: I have done that but my code didn't work.
I don't know how to get the id of the event please help me with code.

Comment: Also help me how to get that value from database for color change.

Comment: If you want to avoid trouble use the API of the calendar as much as possible not some deprecated event listeners  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/

Comment: If someone can help me to get dynamic color value regarding evenyColor: 'dynamic color values from database',...
it will definitely work...please help with perfect code. thanks

Comment: @Barbs can you make a function to update event like event drop I will be very thankful I m not good in jquery or ajax. Please help me.

Comment: @Barbs Sorry I can't do that will you help me???

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the API at all?

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/#options

Here is how you do it with Event-generating function:

```
......
events: function (start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: "json-events.php",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //console.log is to see what you are receiving from server actually (event text,color,id....whaever you send), use google chrome, press F12 to open console
            //here you do whatever you want with your data fetched from server if any modification required
            //just make it look like this finally
            //[event0,event1,event2,.....]
            //Where your event array elements are javascript objects
            //finally give the array to the calendar:

            //callback([event0,event1,event2,.....])
        },
        dataType: /* xml, json, script, or html */
    });
},
....
```

How does each event object within the array look like?
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/
The event properties are at the page I posted you above, but anyway
a javascript object with optional and required properties! I am giving an example with listing all! You decide for yourself which are useful in your case:

```
{
    id: "id value", 
    end: "end date", //when event ends - required field
    start: "start date", // when event starts - required field
    title: "title value",
    textColor: "color value",
    className: "add your style Class",
    backgroundColor: "color value",
    borderColor: "color value",
    editable: "boolean value"
}
```